# Overflow (Error 6) VBA 7.1 - Excel 2019- MAC

Tags: excel, vba

Always the same error with variables defined as Double. I am using the last version of excel. The error is not happening on PC-Windows.

price = 19.99 run into an error (runtime 6 overflow)

This is a code example:
Sub Variables():

```
' Basic String Variable
' ----------------------------------------
Dim name As String
name = "Gandalf"

MsgBox (name)

' Basic String Concatenation (Combination)
' ----------------------------------------
Dim title As String
title = "The Great"

Dim fullname As String
fullname = name + " " + title

MsgBox (fullname)

' Basic Integer, Double, Long Variables
' ----------------------------------------
Dim age1 As Integer
Dim age2 As Integer
age1 = 5
age2 = 10

Dim price As Double
Dim tax As Double
price = 19.99
tax = 0.05

Dim lightspeed As Long
```

Comment: This behavior seems very strange to say the least -- if others can reproduce this it would seem to be a bug (and not something you will be able to readily fix via code), however you may elect to `price = 19.99#` **or** `Dim price as Currency` and see if the error persists in that way?

Comment: Thanks, same error :-(

Comment: Bummer. Well, try posting [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac-mso_2019?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=all&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1) and see if others have encountered same problem? You will need to report a bug to Microsoft probably.